# ngClass combine two expression types

Tags: angular

Using ngClass I am trying to combine two expression types such that they are data bound and updated with changedetection like this

```
<div [ngClass]="[test.value | myClassPipe, {'anotherClass': test.isValid}]"></div>
```

Is the syntax wrong or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the isValid property is being set in myClassPipe, try creating a function for ngClass.

-component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="{'anotherClass': checkIsValid(test)}"></div>
```

-component.ts

```
checkIsValid(test: any){  
     let converted = myClassPipe.transform(test); 
     if(converted.isValid) 
         return true; 
     else  
         return false; 
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

As per [NgClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass) guide, A good way to apply `NgClass` is by binding it to a key:value control object. Each key of the object is a CSS class name; its value is true if the class should be added, false if it should be removed.

Consider a component method such as setClasses that manages the state of three CSS classes:

```
setClasses() {
  let classes =  {
    saveable: this.canSave,      // true
    modified: !this.isUnchanged, // false
    special: this.isSpecial,     // true
  };
  return classes;
}
```

Now we can add an NgClass property binding that calls setClasses and sets the element's classes accordingly:

```
<div [ngClass]="setClasses()">This div is saveable and special</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What about the data binding will setClasses() be triggered  when e.g. this.canSave changes?

Comment: Yes, `saveable` class will be removed if `this.canSave` value is set to `false`

Comment: Great answer! Awesome way to manipulate classes and variables.